# openssl v 1.0.1j issue for generating libssl.a and libcrypto.a

Tags: linux, android-ndk, openssl

I am trying to generate .a files using openssl(1.0.1j) for arm64 and through shell script on Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit with i686 machine)

Showing lots of errors as "unknown mnemonic".

Any simple way to resolve this?

I tried to execute the same commands on 64 bit machine also with x84_64 arch. But still facing the same issues. Can anyone please share some views/ideas about this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of relevant information, like the exact line of code that the error corresponds to, and the makefile you're using to build the library.

Comment: I am using commands mentioned at https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android
The only change is that instead of config I am using Configure with linux-generic64 option.
About the error line no. - actually there were many unknown mnemonic errors. will try to get them again with line no.s

Comment: *instead of config I am using Configure with linux-generic64*  That's likely to be causing a mismatch - "unknown mnemonic" is likely referring to unknown assembler mnemonics, and "lots" of those errors implies a build for the wrong architecture.  First you need to get everything working using the directions posted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Everything works fine for normal "arm7" architecture.  But when we change the arch to "arm64" and obviously other env. variables in .sh file, it says this arch. is not supported. So I tried to do the things mentioned in "INSTALL" file for arm64. There it is mentioned to use "Configure" instead of "config". and by searching on net I got to know about "linux-generic64".